# How do I make an asynchronous function return in .map?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I am trying to get the `fetchIDFromPerson` function to return and assign the returned value to `ID` before the rest of the `fetchPersons` function executes. It is only returning undefined since it's async. What can I do to get it to work?
Thanks.

```
const fetchIDFromPerson = name => {
  axios
    .get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/?search=${name}&format=json`)
    .then(response => extractImgIDFromURL(response.data.results[0].url))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
};

let body;

const fetchPersons = (query, imgID) => {
  SWAPIGraphQL.post("", { query })
    .then(result => {
      const { allPersons } = result.data.data;
      return (body = allPersons.map(person => {
        const ID = fetchIDFromPerson(person.name); //This returns undefined!
        return {
          ...person,
          imgID: ID //needs to be assigned a value from fetchIDFromPerson
        };
      }));
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
};

fetchPersons(GET_PERSONS_DATA);
```

Comment: "*It is only returning undefined since it's async.*" - no, it's returning `undefined` since you forgot to `return` the promise you are creating. (Same in `fetchPersons`, btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a number of changes to properly use the promises that your asynchronous code return:

1. `return` the axios promise to the caller in `fetchIDFromPerson()`.
2. rethrow error in `.catch()` after logging it so the caller sees the error
3. `return` the `return SWAPIGraphQL.post()` promise to the caller in `fetchPersons()`.
4. Get rid of the `body` variable.  You don't want side effect programming, particular with asynchronous code.  Communicate back results through returned promises.
5. Use `Promise.all()` on the results of the `.map()` so you know when all those promises are done.
6. When calling `fetchPersons()` use the returned promise to get the resolved value.
7. Inside the `.map()` return the promise from `fetchIDFromPerson()`.
8. Add a `.then()` to where you call `fetchIDFromPerson()` where you can return the combined data structure with person and ID in it.
9. Change `response.data.results[0].url` to `response.results[0].url` to match the data structure you're getting back.

Here's the fixed up code:

```
const fetchIDFromPerson = name => {
  return axios
    .get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/?search=${name}&format=json`)
    .then(response => extractImgIDFromURL(response.results[0].url))
    .catch(error => {
        // log and rethrow
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    });
};


const fetchPersons = (query, imgID) => {
  return SWAPIGraphQL.post("", { query })
    .then(result => {
      const { allPersons } = result.data.data;
      return Promise.all(allPersons.map(person => {
        return fetchIDFromPerson(person.name).then(ID => {
            return {
              ...person,
               imgID: ID
            };
        });
      }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // log error and rethrow
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    });
};

fetchPersons(GET_PERSONS_DATA).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You can simplify `fetchPersons()` a bit by using `async/await` and not logging the error as many separate places:

```
const fetchPersons = async (query, imgID) => {
    const result = await SWAPIGraphQL.post("", { query });
    const { allPersons } = result.data.data;
    return Promise.all(allPersons.map(async (person) => {
        const ID = await fetchIDFromPerson(person.name);
        return {
          ...person,
           imgID: ID
        };
    }));
};
```

Comment: Check. Check, check, check, check, and check. Maybe add "# drop the `catch` that only rethrows as it gets logged afterwards anyway" and "# use async/await to simplify" :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, I was thinking about adding a simplified version using `async/await`.  Will maybe be able to do that in a bit.

Comment: Added simplified `async/await` implementation.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for cleaning that up. I am still experiencing the issue with "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined". I can't seem to get at that url value before `fetchIDFromPerson` returns.

Comment: @AleksandarZdravkovski - Well, if that's coming from `extractImgIDFromURL(response.data.results[0].url)`, then there's something wrong with that data structure or how you're referencing it.  You will have to debug that yourself.  Start with `console.log(response)` and `console.log(response.data)` and then explore further into the data structure to see where you are off.  If those two look right, then add `console.log(response.data.results)` and if that looks right, then add `console.log(response.data.results[0])`, but by then you will probably see where things went wrong.

Comment: @AleksandarZdravkovski - I figured it out by going to `https://swapi.co/api/people/?search=Luke%20Skywalker&format=json` and looking at the response.  See the edits to my answer.  It looks like you want `response.results[0].url` and you may want to check to make sure that `response.cnt` is at least `1`.

Comment: @AleksandarZdravkovski - Also, is `extractImageFromUrl()` doing something asynchronous.  If so, it may need to be fixed to properly use promises just like your other asynchronous operations here were.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is the body of `extractImgIDFromURL`:
`const extractImgIDFromURL = url => {
  const parts = url.split("/");
  return parts[parts.length - 2];
};`
Nothing async going on here. I did double-check the data structure and everything is logging out correctly. I also did an `if` check to make sure the `response.data.results[0].url` is only passed to the `extractImgIDFromURL` function if it's truthy. Still getting `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`.

Comment: @AleksandarZdravkovski - please see my latest edits. There's no `.data` part of that response that I see unless axios is adding that.

Comment: @jfriend00 It must be axios adding `data`, then, because there's no other way I can `console.log` any of the following levels in the data structure.

Comment: I figured it out. I added this check in my `fetchIDFromPerson` function:
`if (response.data.results[0] && response.data.results[0].url) {
        return extractImgIDFromURL(response.data.results[0].url);
      }`
This checked that the upper level is returnable before proceeding to the `url`.